# Using css3 transitions instead of jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm animating a block of html that fades in (opacity) and moves slightly from the left (margin-left)...

```
$('.latest-stats').delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1, marginLeft: '55px' }, 1000, function () {
  ...code in here
}

.latest-stats {
   position:absolute;
   top:250px;
   opacity:0;
   margin-left:40px;
}
```

There is a delay and I need to perform some functions within that block of HTML after the transiiton has  finished. Can this be done in css, maybe by adding a class that has the transitions upon it?

Answer (score 1):

**The Added CSS Class:**

```
.transitioned {
   opacity:1;
   margin-left:55px;
   transition:all 1s;
   -ms-transition:all 1s;
   -moz-transition:all 1s;
   -o-transition:all 1s;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}
```

**The jQuery:** **(UPDATED)**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.latest-stats').addClass('transitioned');
    setTimeout(function(){
        //your code here
    },1000);
},1000);
```

but I just have to ask, is there a specific reason you wanna do this? I mean what's wrong with the jQuery animate?

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong, the animation isn't as smooth as I would have liked, wanted to see if the css transition would be smoother.

Comment: Separation of concerns would be a very good reason to do this, provided there are fallbacks for browsers that don't support CSS transitions. I'd also suggest using `translate` rather than animating the left margin, as it's typically smoother. Note that `translate` isn't as widely supported as you'd probably like, but coverage is pretty good.

Comment: if you have a lot of animations in your page and you want smooth transition then take a look at GSAP => https://greensock.com/gsap

Comment: Just tried and the above doesn't seem to be firing any code after the class has been added, e.g. if I try to alert something to the screen? I didn't think there was a callback on an addClass?

Comment: check the updated jQuery code, I forgot to mention that the previous code needs jQuery UI library because `addClass` doesn't have a callback by default

Comment: @Dre any chance of an example using `translate`?

Comment: @RobMorris Added example as an answer

Answer (score 1):

We rejig the JS to just add the class rather than the any styles:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.latest-stats').toggleClass('transitioned').each(function () {
        // Call back functions here
    });
}, 1000);
```

I use `setTimeout()` since `delay()` only works for animations. I use `each()` to add my callback function, since `toggleClass()` doesn't have a callback, and this way I don't need to load an extra library.

Then the CSS handles the changes to the styles, keeping all the visual aspects in one location:

`.latest-stats {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:40px;
    padding: 30px;
    background:red;
    margin:40px;
}
.latest-stats.transitioned {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:translate(55px, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate(55px, 0);
    transform:translate(55px, 0);
}`

Note I'm using `translate` to shift the element rather than `margin-left` as [the browser doesn't have to change the layout or perform a repaint on the element, which can improve the animation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/). However, check for browser support and provide fallbacks when necessary/appropriate.

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/awy0o8ev/)